# Merge DictionaryResource from Application in a ClassLibrary

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 solution that has a Standard Application Project and a Class Library Project. The idea is that I can, somehow, `StaticResources` down do the ClassLibrary so it can override the existing ones. I'll give you an example:
In my ClassLibrary I have a `ClassLibraryDictionary.xaml` with the following code:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ClassLibraryTest">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyButtonColor" Color="#FF0000FF" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the idea is that in my MainApplication I could have a Dictionary.xaml with the same `StaticResource` Key, and pass it to my ClassLibrary so it can override the default property, something like:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MainApplicationTest">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyButtonColor" Color="#00FF00FF" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And passing it in code:

```
var mainAppDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
mainAppDictionary.Source = new Uri("/using:MainApplicationTest;component/MainApplicationDictionary.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
classLibraryTest.SetResourceDictionary(mainAppDictionary);
```

The problem here is that I can't seem to use the ResourceDictionary instance in my ClassLibrary, and I'm not even sure this is the best way to do this.
So, how could I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to this and it is actually simple. The path I was using was not the correct one, so to sum it all up, the solution in XAML, if you were to do it in the `App.xaml` (in the MainApp) looks like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx://Common/yourclasslibraryname/ClassLibraryDictionary.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Dictionary1.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

If you want to set it in code directly in the ClassLibrary you can do something like this:
In the `MainApp.xaml.cs`

```
myClassLibrary.MergeAllDictionaries(App.Current.Resources);
```

And in the `ClassLibrary`:

```
public void MergeAllDictionaries(ResourceDictionary appDictionary) {
    // First copy all keys from MainApp to a new Dictionary
    ResourceDictionary mainDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
    foreach(var keys in appDictionary.MergedDictionaries) {
        foreach(var keys1 in keys) {
            mainDictionary.Add(keys1.Key, keys1.Value);
        }
    }

    // Then clear all
    appDictionary.Clear();

    // Get the ClassLibrary dictionary
    ResourceDictionary classLibraryDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
    classLibraryDictionary.Source = new Uri("ms-appx://Common/yourclasslibraryname/ClassLibraryDictionary.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    // First add the ClassLibrary keys and values
    appDictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(classLibraryDictionary);
    // Then add the old values, so that they overwrite the ClassLibrary ones
    appDictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(mainDictionary);
}
```